# Import Data into MySQL table from CSV file without Overwriting Existing Data

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a csv file with data that I want to import into a table.  Some of the data already exists in the table and I don't want to add a duplicate row.

For example, I have apple in a row in the table, and apple in a row in the CSV file with additional information.

I don't want a new row added to the table or to overwrite any of the data in the existing row; just add the additional data for that row from the CSV file into the table row.

How can I avoid a duplicate row being added or overwriting data, or do I even have to worry about this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `LOAD DATA INFILE IGNORE`.

See the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

> If you specify IGNORE, rows that duplicate an existing row on a unique key value are discarded.